# Cannot run flutter project on emulator

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I have downloaded Android Studio Chipmunk|2021.2.1 Patch 1
I have java version 8 (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
I am trying to run main.dart (default flutter  program ) on vscode but it does not work\

I have run flutter doctor command to check for any issues but everything is correct
[image]

The error list is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'G:\proj\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:4.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:common:27.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:27.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:27.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/7.0/asm-commons-7.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/7.0/asm-commons-7.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/7.0/asm-util-7.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/7.0/asm-util-7.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
      > Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc1.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-metadata/0.1.0-rc1/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-metadata/0.1.0-rc1/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/7.0/asm-tree-7.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/7.0/asm-tree-7.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
      > Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'.            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake
..........
```

My gradle wrapper properties:

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

My build gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flut"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I read some issues regarding gradle incompatibility but i don't quite understand it well and i don't get why these errors are occurring exactly.

UPDATE: I tried some fixes and the error list has now reduced to this

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s\
```

I think there is some issue of TLS protocol version. But i can't find much detail about it.

Comment: Are you running the project for the first time? If so, you should first be connected to the internet so that gradle can properly download and resolve all dependencies from the internet.

Comment: @JustaPerson  Uhm well the project did run well for once yesterday. But then i updated android studio and java and then this issue started. Also i have been connected to the internet all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Open Flutter Terminal and run:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Then update your classpath:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by open flutter terminal?

Comment: okay i tried this but this does not work